Consulta multiples tablas php, sql
Tengo el siguiente problema
tengo una tabla con unas secuencias de horarios del día

06:00 - 07:00

07:00 - 08:00

(así sucesivamente)


En otra tabla tengo un catálogo de piezas con su información, y tengo una tercera tabla donde constantemente se registran piezas producidas

Necesito generar un listado con las horas de la primera tabla y que mediante ese intervalo de horas me cuente cuantas piezas se han producido y determinar cuántas piezas me están faltando de producir
La manera en la que lo realice en este momento es una consulta SQL donde obtengo todas las horas mediante un while, dentro de ese while estoy realizando otra consulta con la que voy contando las piezas producidas entre esas horas.
Pero al momento de que cambian de pieza producida en el lapso del día, ya no muestra el nuevo artículo producido
Me lo deveria de mostrar de esta manera, con las horas sin registros ya que aun no se ingresa nada a esa hora, pero solo si es el mismo Job me muestra el listado asi

cuando el Job cambia me trunca la tabla, y no me muestra el job nuevo ingresado

    $query=sqlsrv_query($con, "SELECT *  FROM Horarios ");
    while ($Horarios=sqlsrv_fetch_array($query)) 
    {
     $HoraInicio=$Horarios["HoraInicio"]->format("H:i");
     $HoraFin=$Horarios["HoraFin"]->format("H:i");
     $query1=sqlsrv_query($con, "SELECT Job, COUNT(*) AS Total FROM Tbl_Produccion_Scan WHERE Fecha_Scan=CONVERT (date, GETDATE()) and Semana='202415'and Turno='Turno 1' and Hora_Scan between '$HoraInicio' And '$HoraFin' group by job");
       while ($List1=sqlsrv_fetch_array($query1)) 
        {
         $Job = $List1["Job"];
         $Total = $List1["Total"];
          $query3=sqlsrv_query($con, "SELECT * FROM CatalogoNoParte WHERE Job='$Job' ");
          while ($CatParte=sqlsrv_fetch_array($query3)) 
           {
            $NoParte = $CatParte["NoParte"];
            $Operadores = $CatParte["Operadores"];
            $Standar = $CatParte["Std"];
            $CantidadT=$Standar - $Total;
           }
        }
    }


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! y si nos mostras las tablas? seguro hay una forma mejor de hacerlo. Igual no queda claro que problema te da este codigo...

No entiendo el problema y las tablas. Veo que en tbl_produccion_scan hay una fila para el job 3514088 a las 10:08:04. Este job tiene dos filas en catalogonoparte, el número del parte es lo mismo (00278-R10-S00), pero la linea es diferente (Range 1, Range 2). Las dos filas tienen 10 operadores cada una. Entonces, ¿han producido un parte 00278-R10-S00 con veinte operadores a las 10:08:04? ¿Y a las 10:08:22 otra parte con veinte operadores? ¿Y en 10:08:38 otra vez? ¿Qué es Std? ¿Hay que mostrar la suma, el máximo, el mínimo o la media? ¿Y en el resultado quieres una fila por horario y parte?

Y si hay un rango de horas sin fila en tbl_produccion_scan, ¿hay que mostrar la fila con parte NULL y cero operadores? ¿Y algo no funciona con tu código? Los datos de las tablas que estas mostrando no encajan con los resultados. Por ejemplo, solamente muestras filas de tbl_produccion_scan a las diez y poco, pero tu resultado contiene valores de las 6:00-7:00. Por favor solamente muestra algunas filas de las tablas con un resultado correspondiente. (No imágenes, pero texto formateado.)

Estás realizando una consulta para cada intervalo de tiempo y luego otra consulta para cada pieza producida dentro de ese intervalo. Este enfoque puede ser ineficiente y difícil de manejar, especialmente si tienes muchos intervalos de tiempo y piezas producidas. Una solución más eficiente y escalable sería realizar una única consulta SQL que agrupe los datos por intervalo de tiempo y pieza producida, y luego procesar los resultados en PHP. Esto reduciría significativamente el número de consultas a la base de datos y haría que el código sea más fácil de mantener y escalar.
SELECT 
    HoraInicio, HoraFin, Job, COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM 
    Horarios H
JOIN 
    Tbl_Produccion_Scan P ON P.Hora_Scan BETWEEN H.HoraInicio AND H.HoraFin
WHERE 
    P.Fecha_Scan = CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) AND P.Semana = '202415' AND P.Turno = 'Turno 1'
GROUP BY 
    H.HoraInicio, H.HoraFin, P.Job

